# Accessing 'messages' relationship using Eloquent's with() method inside react map() function

Tags: reactjs, laravel, eloquent, lazy-loading

Tables 'users' and 'messages' have a relationship and am using with() function to access users and their messages there is a field 'is_read' inside messages table so when i map() over users in react component, how can i access the users.messages.is_read inside the map function.

controller

```
public function messageDisplay($recipientId)
    {
        $currentUser = Auth::user();
        $recipientUser = User::findOrFail($recipientId);

        // Fetch all users except the currently logged-in user
        $users = User::with('messages')->where('id', '<>', $currentUser->id)->get();

        // Fetch all messages for the current chat (between $currentUser and $recipientUser)
        $messages = Message::where(function ($query) use ($currentUser, $recipientUser) {
            $query->where('sender_id', $currentUser->id)
                ->where('recipient_id', $recipientUser->id);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($currentUser, $recipientUser) {
            $query->where('sender_id', $recipientUser->id)
                ->where('recipient_id', $currentUser->id);
        })->orderBy('created_at')->get();

        // Update the read status of the messages that belong to the recipient
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            if ($message->recipient_id === $currentUser->id && !$message->is_read) {
                $message->update(['is_read' => true]);
            }
        }

        // dd($users);

        return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
            'currentUser' => $currentUser,
            'users' => $users, // Pass the list of users to the view
            'messages' => $messages,
            'recipientId' => $recipientId,
        ]);
    }
```

React component

```
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Useravatar from '../Profile/Useravatar'
import { MessageContext } from '../Dashboard';
import { useContext } from 'react';


const Sidebarheader = ({ users }) => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const messages = useContext( MessageContext );
    console.log(users, messages);
    const activeUsersCount = Object.values(users).length;
  return (
    <>
        <div
            className="hidden md:flex fixed left-0 top-0 h-full flex-col py-8
                    pl-6 pr-2 w-64 bg-white overflow-y-auto flex-shrink-0">


            <div className="flex flex-col">
                <h2 className='font-bold pb-6'>Recents</h2>
                <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between text-xs">
                        <span className="font-bold">Active Conversations</span>
                        <span
                        className="flex items-center justify-center
                        bg-gray-300 h-4 w-4 rounded-full"
                        >{activeUsersCount}</span>
                </div>

                {/* iterating through the users displaying the users in the sidebar component */ }
                { Object.values(users).map( user => (
                    <Link key={ user.id }
                    className="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold"
                    to={`/dashboard/${user.id}`}>

                        <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1 mx-2 overflow-y-auto">
                            <button
                                className="flex flex-row items-center
                                hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
                                >

                                <Useravatar
                                    userName={ user.name }
                                />

                                <div className="ml-2 text-sm font-normal">{user.name}</div>


                            </button>


                        </div>
                    </Link>
                ))}


                <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between text-xs mt-6">
                    <span className="font-bold">Archived</span>
                    <span
                    className="flex items-center justify-center
                    bg-gray-300 h-4 w-4 rounded-full"
                    >7
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1 mt-4 -mx-2">
                        <button
                        className="flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
                        >
                            <div
                                className="flex items-center justify-center
                                h-8 w-8 bg-indigo-200 rounded-full"
                            >
                                H
                            </div>
                            <div className="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold">Henry Boyd</div>
                        </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Sidebarheader
```